# Configure Postgre DB in docker project

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm very new to docker and docker-compose things. I have tried to use Kiwi TCMS open source project which supposed to use with Docker.

My question is can I run the projects on docker on the same server, I'm supposed to configure my development and production sites on the same server (CentOS)?

I'm following the below link to install docker and configure the kiwitcms application for the first time, I read the basics about the docker and how its working and all.

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#

I want to use PostgreSQL as my Database, but the existing latest docker image has MariaDB. So after I pulled latest version of kiwitcms from docker hub using the following command,

docker pull kiwitcms/kiwi

Should I change to "docker-compose.yml" file db image value, and save it to a local new directory,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/master/docker-compose.yml

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Also there can we edit use our own DB name, user name passwords right?

then execute the following command.

docker-compose up -d

I'm very new to this model and read most of the articles related to docker, but this leads me few of these doubts, hence asking for these clarifications.

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

The web app and the DB server are 2 different images (aka 2 different servers). For example how we use Postgres in testing see:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/blob/master/docker-compose.postgres